# DataTable showing "Cannot read property 'each' of null"

Tags: javascript, datatable

I've being trying to implement data table,but its not working.Checking with my google chrome debugger;it returns error that "Cannot read property 'each' of null".I've been trying to debug this but am not getting it through.

here is a reference to the website, to see examples http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html

Below here is the code:

sortable.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $('#example thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // Apply the search
    table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) {
        $( 'input', table.column( colIdx ).footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            table
                .column( colIdx )
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        } );
    } );
} );
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<!--INCLUDE JQUERY-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{JS('jquery-1.11.0.min.js')}}"></script>
<!--INCLUDE DATAtABLE JQUERY RESOURCE-->    
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{JS('jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
 </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

i actually required the sortable in my master file coz am using laravel,and when i did enter $('#example tfoot th') into my console it returned an array of this:
[
​Name​​
, 
​Position​​
, 
​Office​​
, 
​Age​​
, 
​Start date​​
, 
​Salary​​
]

but looking at the source file on the debugger i discovered that the error is shown on the line where i have  "table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx )".

but am sorry i dont get the part of the breakpoint; cuz what i tried is to add "break;" after the line

Answer (score 1):

open the page in Chrome's Web Developer Tools and go to console (or simply press esc). Enter:

```
$('#example tfoot th')
```

and press enter. See what it evaluates to. If it can't find any elements, then there's your problem. Considering the html you supplied, I doubt this is going to be your problem (unless you have a more serious problem with jQuery and where it looks).

Therefor, the problem should be on the second .each(). Go to sources in Web Developer Tools, open sortable.js file and put a breakpoint on the line with

```
table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx )
```

and refresh the page. Once the breakpoint has been hit, enter in the console:

```
table.columns()
```

and see what it evaluates to. My guess is it's going to be null.

I don't see where you've included sortable.js. Did you include it after requiring dataTables.min.js?

Comment: checking my source in the debugger its on the line table.columns().eq( 0 ).each( function ( colIdx ) that it throws the error.

Comment: thanks solved the problem already!!. it was something with the way am calling my sripts

Comment: @AlofeOluwafemi What was the solution?

Comment: @AlofeOluwafemi you should have posted the solution that solved your problem, that could help other if they come across the same problem